# How to modify pdf, which has 6 slides per page

Tags: pdf, printing

here's my PDF file: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F54C52F1CF8C7ED9!69044&authkey=!AK44qMi9E5X0YVU&ithint=file%2cpdf

It has 6 slides per page and I'd like to print it in a format of 2 (or maybe 4) slides per page. Do you know how can I achieve that?

Comment: If you have the native presentation file, you could possibly do it. But straight from PDF I doubt if you could do it

Comment: I only have the PDF file. I hope someone knows the way to rearrange the slides.